# RVM install Ruby 2.1.2: configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long)

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

While installing ruby with:

> rvm install 2.1.2

I am getting this error.
And I have also tried building ruby 2.1.2 and other versions as well from source, but I am getting the same error while running:

> ./configure

OSX Version: 10.14.2 (18C54)
Rvm Version: 1.29.4

This error started coming up after I upgraded to OSX Mojave.

Logs:

> ruby-2.1.2 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.2 - please wait
>   Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
>   No binary rubies available for: osx/10.14/x86_64/ruby-2.1.2.
>   Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
>   Checking requirements for osx.
>   Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' is already up to date.
>   Requirements installation successful.
>   Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/shubhams/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
>   ruby-2.1.2 - #downloading ruby-2.1.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
>   ruby-2.1.2 - #extracting ruby-2.1.2 to /Users/shubhams/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.2 - please wait
>   ruby-2.1.2 - #applying patch 
> /Users/shubhams/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.1.2/openssl3.patch - please wait
>   ruby-2.1.2 - #configuring - please wait
>   Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/shubhams/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2  --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --enable-shared',
>   please read /Users/shubhams/.rvm/log/1544095614_ruby-2.1.2/configure.log
>   There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

Log inside "/Users/shubhams/.rvm/log/1544095614_ruby-2.1.2/configure.log":

> ....
>   checking for long long... yes
>   checking for off_t... yes
>   checking char bit... 8
>   checking size of int... 0
>   checking size of short... 0
>   checking size of long... 0
>   checking size of long long... configure: error: in 
>   `/Users/shubhams/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.2':
>   configure: error: cannot compute sizeof (long long)
>   See`config.log' for more details

Thanks.

Comment: Try renaming your /usr/local/include to /usr/local/include_old & then try again.

Comment: Thanks @AadityaMaheshwari that seemed to work for me. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, renaming the `/usr/local/include` directory *does* solve this particular issue. This works because the installer script can no longer find the file causing the problem, previously located in the folder formerly known as `/usr/local/include`.

While this works, it is likely you'll later encounter issues with homebrew formulaes (stuff already installed on your machine via homebrew).

**Solution:**

Although this may not always be the case, I simply needed to delete `/usr/local/include/stdint.h`